# javascript injection through URL

Tags: javascript, html

I have done so much work with javascript after loading the page, with injecting the code in the url section inside the browser like :

```
javascript:document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
```

or even insert a link in head section inside the html code to add a css file
all that using only javascript in the URL
but I couldn't change an attribute of an element using that trick .. I tried :

```
javascript:document.getElementById('div').getAttribute('style')='/my style text'
```

I thought there's a problem with my code so I tried again this:

```
javascript:alert(javascript:document.getElementById('div').getAttribute('style'));
```

and it pops-up with the value of style attribute

Why can't I change attribute values using javascript in the URL?

Comment: First, you probably want to set the `style` **property** (but I guess it's not up to me)...like `element.style.prop = "value";`. Second, `getAttribute` returns the value of an attribute as a string...you would need to use `setAttribute("style", "value")` if you want to set the whole attribute

Comment: style can be a property if i use it whiting the javascript code .. i was talking about attribute not property .. style was just an example .. i wanted to change another attribute ..
you people don't have to be mean .. -2 ! that's too bad ! come on !
you don't encourage people to ask questions here .. i wanted to have +16 so i can add points to other users .. now i only have 14 ! thanks guys ! thanks guys that's really awsome !

Answer (score 2):

`getAttribute()` is a function that returns a string.  To change an attribute you use `setAttribute()`.  See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute).

However, to set specific style attributes you should reference the [style property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style).

Comment: can you delete your answer so i can delete my question ?